# JQuery select only direct childs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I tried to select only direct `tr` childs of table using `$('#my_table tbody > tr')` selector, but it doesn't work : if I have a table inside any `tr` element, it will also select the `tr` childs in that table.

How can I achieve the behavior I want ?

Comment: `$('#my_table>tbody > tr')`

Comment: Nested tables are a good indication that you shouldn't be using tables in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin : Then what should I use ?

Comment: @servabat — appropriate semantic markup for the content you have

Comment: @servabat: Nobody can tell you what you need without knowing your objective. Quentin is just saying that nested tables serves as an indicator that you're likely taking the wrong approach. It's not an absolute, but it's a fairly well-established principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting all the `tr` children of *any* `tbody` element that is a descendant of the specified table.

You need to limit your selector so you only get the `tbody` elements that are *children* of that table.

```
#my_table > tbody > tr
```

Comment: The deepest table (the one inside each `tr`) doesn't have `tbody` element.

Comment: @servabat — Yes it does. All tables have tbody elements. They are mandatory. (Although the start and end *tags* for those elements are optional).

Comment: Indeed, it works. So jQuery doesn't match actual markup scheme but some underlying scheme ?

Comment: JavaScript (for which jQuery is a library), CSS, and just about everything else operates on the DOM not the markup.

Comment: _jQuery, CSS, just about everything operates on the DOM not the markup._...These are golden words :)

Comment: @servabat: The browser receives HTML markup and parses it according to a specification. That spec has very detailed rules for what markup items must, may or may not be present at any given location. As the parsing takes place, it create a *document object model* (DOM), and inserts missing items where needed, provides optional items if needed, and often relocates incorrectly placed items when required. This is why understanding the semantic meaning of HTML is important.